# Having trouble using Python extension for SQL

Tags: python, sql

I had IT install SQL Server 2017 V17.9.1, with the Python extension, I even saved the "success" screen to preserve my sanity. Then I tried calling "execute sp_execute_external_script" from within SQL Server Management Studio, which failed with "Could not find stored procedure 'sp_execute_external_script'", then I tried "EXEC sp_configure  'external scripts enabled', 1; RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE", which also failed with "The configuration option 'external scripts enabled' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option". So why can't I call Python from SQL as described? Someone tried to give me the client / server lecture, asserting that "installing SQL" only installs the SQL server, not the client, which is causing my problem - I'm skeptical about that explanation, but would really appreciate the mystery being solved please.

Comment: **SSMS V17.9.1** (client tool) != **SQL Server 2017** (server side) `SELECT @@Version` to check which version you're using

Comment: Thank you for that tip! Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (Intel X86)   Feb  9 2007 22:47:07   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 6.2 (Build 9200: )

Comment: SQL Server 2005 is outdated, SQL Server 2008 end of life is in July. You should consider upgrading your SQL Server instance.

Comment: What do you mean by Python extension? If you mean machine learning services, Python and R, those services were available starting in SQL Server 2016+. If not please post attempted Python code that connects to MSSQL.